# OP comments should be coloured differently

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

My questions often generate a lot of comments. And it is difficult to say whats going on for users who just want an answer and not to read through pages of debates.

I think that if the OP comments will be of **slightly** different colour (say very light green background or something) this might give better and more efficient understanding of what is going on there.

Answer (score 7):

Er, this is already the case.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/

[image]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/question-owner-comment-highlighting.png))</sub>

Comment: OK I meant - the background of the comment not just user name... but thanks

Comment: @bobb that would be super obnoxious, so if that's your request I am going to decline it. Sorry.

Comment: nothing to be sorry of.. i am just asking.. thanks for giving it a thought anyway

Comment: Am I the only person who thinks this box is hard to see on some sites? ProgSE, for example?

Comment: @John no you're not the only who thinks so. User name coloring in comments **[at Programmers looks laughable to me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vC3ZU.png "screen shot")** - in Windows 7 and XP, in Firefox and in IE

Comment: @gnat Yep, that's exactly what I see in Chromium on Ubuntu.